# Selecting common data between two indentical tables with three primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, ssms, primary-key

I have two tables, say table1 and table2. They have the exact same columns and primary keys and have the exact same purpose. Altho, table2 is newer than table1 and have newer data. I want to merge them but first I'm going to have to delete the data from table1 that is already in table2.

Here's my pseudo code:

```
Delete from table1 
where pk1, pk2, pk3 in (select pk1, pk2, pk3 from table2)
```

Is it as simple as querying:

```
Delete from table1 
where pk1 in (select pk1 from table2) 
  and pk2 in (select pk2 from table2) 
  and pk3 in (select pk3 from table2)
```

For example in `Table1` we have:

```
pk1 | pk2 | pk3
000 | 001 | 001
000 | 002 | 001
000 | 002 | 002
```

`Table2` we have:

```
pk1 | pk2 | pk3
000 | 001 | 001
ABC | 002 | 001
ABC | 002 | 002
```

If I use the select statement, I should only get the first row of data, since the other rows have unique data in them.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the data in the two tables would start off looking like, and what the end result should be?  It may not be as simple as just doing one delete, if data also has to move between the two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than deleting from Table1, you could use an `LEFT JOIN` instead to identify which lines do not exist within Table1 - then insert all of the new data at the same time, resulting in only one query rather than two:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT Table2.* FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 
    ON Table2.pk1 = Table1.pk1 
    AND Table2.pk2 = Table1.pk2 
    AND Table2.pk3 = Table1.pk3
WHERE Table1.pk1 IS NULL
```

Any Table1 data that doesn't match all of the requirements specified in the left join parameters will be returned as `NULL` - therefore only one pk column is necessary in the `WHERE` statement.

EDIT: As you're looking to update new values into rows that already exist, you can replace `WHERE Table1.pk1 IS NULL` to the following:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Table1.X = Table2.X, Table1.Y = Table2.Y etc.
```

This is under the assumption that you already have a unique index applied to your three pk values (It should be your primary key) - and if you don't, apply the following to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_idx PRIMARY KEY (pk1, pk2, pk3);
```

Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Can I use the same query to insert the all the rows in to Table2 instead of Table1? 
Or do I need to change anything other than the first line?

Comment: You would have to make a few adjustments to it, but it is possible - `INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON ... WHERE Table2.pk1 IS NULL`.

Comment: Ahhh. I found a problem. We don't only want to merge them, we want all the newer data to be moved to table1 as well as replace the ones with the same pk1, 2,and 3, but have updates on it's other columns. Which is why my original question was to delete those rows in table1. We can't also merge them in to table2, since we'd want to keep table2 as a back up. So as of now, we can't use the code that only skips them.

Comment: Do you need the original data from table1 as a further backup?

Comment: No since it's where we're inserting the rows from table2.

Comment: No problem then! I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE T1
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table2 T2
              WHERE T1.pk1 = T2.pk1
                AND T1.pk2 = T2.pk2
                AND T1.pk3 = T2.pk3);
```

The SQL you have provided probably won't work as you expect. For example, if you have the following rows in `Table1`:

```
1,4,5
6,2,7
8,9,3
```

And the following row in `Table2`:

```
1,2,3
```

No rows would be deleted in `Table1` as all those ID's exist in `Table2`.

Comment: Ahh so what's the difference between what you provided and what I provided?
Wouldn't it actually be correct if it weren't going to delete any data? Since that is what we're going for. If `Table2` has `1,4,5` that would be deleted in `Table1` correct?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean in your latter part of that comment, @MartianMarcera . As for the former, your SQL is only checking the other ID exists in the table anyway, I am checking all 3 keys match at the same time.

Comment: For example if table1 has:
1,4,5 | 
6,2,7 | 
8,9,3

And table2 has:
1,2,3 | 1,4,5. What would be deleted if we use your SQL?

Comment: Just the `1,4,5` row.